# If the bid price is the same, what determines who gets the stock first?

Tags: stocks, bid-ask

For example, if there's already 500 bids for a stock at $1.00 and I put down 100 bids for $1.00 as well, does it mean if someone wants to sell for $1.00, it has to go through the 500 bids before me first before it gets sold to me, or is it random as long as the bid price is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orders are filled based on price and time priority.

PRICE: The lowest sell and highest buy orders take precedence over other orders.

TIME: The earliest order placed at a given price takes precedence over other orders at that price.